# Codemirror: Own Module Keywords

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I try to write my owm module, for our own script language for codemirror.Right know I am hanging on our keywords.

I have this test-code:

```
Window(EditWin, SELECT_MULTIPLE, NO_SIZE, 310, 87, 500, 60, T("Sitzungsdatum", "Session date"))
{
     Prompt(SessionDatePmt, 11, 4, T("Sitzungsdatum", "Session date"))
     Date(SessionDate, 175, 4, 88)

     Button(SystemDateAsSessionDateBtn, 290, 3, 190, 10, T("Übernehme Systemdatum", "Get system date"))
     [ SELECT: SystemObject Call(SystemDate) PutObject(, SessionDate) ]
}
```

And some of our Keywords are:

- Window
- SELECT_MULTIPLE
- NO_SIZE
- Prompt
- Date
- Button
- Select
- SystemObject
- Call
- PutObject

For my regular expression, I use an array, called cons, with all keywords.

Then i join all the array entrys like this:

```
var keywordRegex = new RegExp("\\b(("+cons.join(")|(")+"))\\b");
```

Till there everything works fine. The regular expression i get, does work in normal javascript match(). I even fetched the text of my site using jQuery, and than used the regular expression, and got what I wanted.

But, when I do:

```
if (stream.match(keywordRegex)) return 'keyword';
```

in Codemirror, the Date of SessionDate is matched too.

Here is my whole Codemirror mode:

```
(function(mod) {
    if (typeof exports == "object" && typeof module == "object") // CommonJS
        mod(require("../../lib/codemirror"));
    else if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) // AMD
        define(["../../lib/codemirror"], mod);
    else // Plain browser env
        mod(CodeMirror);
})(function(CodeMirror) {
    "use strict";
    CodeMirror.defineMode("testmode", function() {
        var cons = ['Window', 'SELECT_MULTIPLE', 'NO_SIZE', 'PROMPT', 'Date', 'Button', 'Select', 'SystemObject', 'Call', 'PutObject'];
        var keywordRegex = new RegExp("\\b(("+cons.join(")|(")+"))\\b");
        var numLiteral = /(-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|0x[0-9a-f]+)/;
        return {
            token: function(stream, state) {
                if (stream.match(/^('([^']|\\.)*'?|"([^"]|\\.)*"?)/))
                    return "string";


                if (stream.match(keywordRegex)) return 'keyword';
                if (stream.match(/({|})/)) return "bracket";
                if (stream.match(numLiteral)) return "number";
                if (stream.match(/(->)/)) return "arrow";


                stream.next();
                return null;
            },
            startState: function() {
              return {
                pair: false,
                pairStart: false,
                keyCol: 0,
                inlinePairs: 0,
                inlineList: 0,
                literal: false,
                escaped: false
              };
            }
        };
    });

    CodeMirror.defineMIME("application/testmode", "testmode");
});
```

## Edit:

As asked for, here is a working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bPyuJd?p=preview

There you can see, I don't have a keyword "SessionDate", but because of the Keyword "Date", the "Date" of "SessionDate" gets highlighted too.

Comment: Just a wild guess: you're consuming char by char for each token.. shouldn't the `keywordRegex` (and all others) be anchored to `^` ?

Comment: I added a working example as requested. the "^" for the start of a string, or of a line, isn't solving my problem either :/ but thanks for the try! :D

Comment: Try `var keywordRegex = new RegExp("\\b(("+cons.join(")|(")+"))\\b(?![^()]*\\))");`, it will just avoid highlighting inside round brackets. Not sure you need exactly this, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no, not exactly.

When i have 
`(EditWin, SELECT_MULTIPLE)`
Than **EditWin** should be black (not highlighted) and **SELECT_MULTIPLE** shoulbe be highlighted as a keyword.

If i have somthing like `(Date, SessionDate)`, than **SessionDate** should be unhighlightet, but **Date** should be highlighted as keyword.

\b should do the job, but it does not work in codemirror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I have found a way to  solve it. There is [no support for anchors in Code Mirror](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/commit/2f162eeec682d24f5252de26474d55cff01c90db):

> (The `^` regexp marker doesn't work as you'd expect in
>    this context because of limitations in JavaScript's RegExp
>    API.)

Thus, use 2 regexps for the beginning of string condition and a mid-string position, and for the start-of-string position, check the position with `stream.sol()`:

```
var keywordRegex = new RegExp("("+cons.join("|")+")(?=\\W)");
var midkeywordRegex = new RegExp("\\W("+cons.join("|")+")(?=\\W)");

...

if (stream.sol() && stream.match(/('([^']|\\.)*'?|"([^"]|\\.)*"?)/))
    return "iv-string";

if (stream.sol() && stream.match(keywordRegex)) return 'keyword';
if (stream.match(midkeywordRegex)) return 'keyword';
```

See [Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zmsMwCtPcUDBgZUO0n9k?p=preview)

Comment: The only drawback is that the initial non-word character will also be highlighted. If it is not whitespace, it might not be nice, but I do not see a way to make it better at this point.

Comment: Nice catch! One more item to the list of JavaScript dont's.